# Traffic not routed through VPN connection when connected by network-manager

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, wireguard

I'm trying to use wireguard vpn with NetworkManage, but i have a problem with routes. When I connect with exact same settings via `wg-quick`, it works perfectly, but NetworkManager adds unneeded routes as I may see, and i just want to know how to prevent it from doing so. wireguard uses fwmark, and i think this routes from networkmanager just break everything.
NetworkManager wireguard plugin I use: https://github.com/max-moser/network-manager-wireguard

So, when i connect via network-manager, I can access the VPN server itself via vpn network, but all traffic still goes as there is no vpn. When connected via `wg-quick` everything works as expected.

Output of `ip r` and `route -n` when connected from NetworkManager:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.100.100.0/24 dev usa proto kernel scope link src 10.100.100.2 metric 50 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlo1 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.100 metric 600 

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
10.100.100.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     50     0        0 usa
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlo1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1
```

When connected with `wg-quick up`:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlo1 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.100 metric 600

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlo1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1
```

Comment: Considering that Wireguard and the Network Manager Wireguard plugin are still considered non-stable software this question may be better suited to the issue queue from the network-manager-wireguard project on github.com.

Comment: @frederickjh well that done at the same time i posted this question here, but no response from the developer, maybe the project is abandoned.

Comment: Do you have a link to the issue you created in the Wireguard issue queue?